# Primefaces Datable liveScroll + lazy loading - filter not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, lazy-loading

Using PrimeFaces 5.0.

My datatable uses lazy loading and live scrolling and I try to filter both fields:

```html
<p:dataTable id="eventsTable" value="#{eventController.eventModel}" var="event" lazy="true"
   scrollRows="100" liveScroll="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500">
   <p:column headerText="EID" filterBy="#{enent.eid}">
      <h:outputText value="#{event.eid}" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Type" filterBy="#{event.type}">
      <h:outputText value="#{event.type}" />
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The initial load retrieves data correctly, and live scrolling seems to work fine.

But when I try to filter one of the fields the datatable is completely emptied (It does not even show the "No records found" message). When I debug I can see that my queries are executed correctly and return data.

Also, If I switch using paging instead of liveScroll, pages are lazy loaded correctly and filters also work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You must set the rows attribute of the datatable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Try to set the rows attribute and then it will work. It is the answer of your question. And not delete my post before you've try it. On your datatable tag you must add rows="100" the same number as you have for scroll rows

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  I had scrollRows set, but not rows.